# Are thread shared variables directly accessed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model

Reading about the C++ memory model and ordering directives raised me a questions - in the same process when a thread-shared atomic variable (eg. atomic) is set in one thread - and the ordering of the load is after the store - is it possible that the load is not seeing the stored value?

Rephrased - is ordering a guarantee that a set atomic value is loaded as is, or there is a CPU/cache/etc abstraction that could still provide an older value?

The reason of the questions is some literature talks about synchronization (apart from ordering) and the language they use is "as seen by another thread" - which makes me wonder if load is not a direct access to the memory location (which would not need any other synchronization than ordering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I can try to provide some details about the C++ memory model.

The default memory order of all operations on C++ atomics is *sequential consistent*. Formally this means that there is a single total order (*S*) of all sequentially consistent operations (regardless by which thread the are executed). So if a thread *A* performs a seq-cst-store on some variable *X*, and thread *B* performs a seq-cst-load on *X*, and the store is ordered before the load in *S*, then it is guaranteed that *B* sees the value stored by *A* (or some newer value).

However, once you use more relaxed memory orderings for your operations you lose this guarantee, because these more relaxed atomic operations are generally *unordered*. However, you can introduce orderings by means of a *happens-before relation* between certain operations. E.g., an acquire-load that sees the value written by a release-store *synchronizes-with* that store, thereby establishing a happens-before relation.

The C++ memory model is certainly one of the more complex aspects of the language and can not be thoroughly explained in a simple answer. For more details I recommend further reading like this paper which I have co-authored: [Memory Models for C/C++ Programmers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04432)
It not only covers the C++ memory model, but also gives a brief overview over the memory models of x86 and ARM/Power, trying to explain why it is even *necessary* to have a memory model in the first place.

Comment: After having a lot of confusion what helped me getting closer (I believe) is two things - first is the concept of a thread dependent "memory", just like you write in your paper you've linked, as well as in [The C++ memory model: an intuition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyNG4qiWnmU) that shows some visual release-acquire examples.
The other detail that helped is the fact that when talking about ordering it's not the execution ordering but the memory sync ordering - so a physical execution order for one thread can be differently _seen_ by other threads.
Much appreciate for the pointers!